# Expanding within the same df

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, expand

I am looking for expanding my dataset based on any number e.g., (5)

I have the following data set

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": ["A", "B" ], "Y": [2, 1 ]})
print (df)
```

and I want to expand it by 5 and the ending dataset should look like the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B" ], "Y": [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]})
print (df)
```

I have a very big dataset and would like expansion in a same dataframe instead of creating a new dataframe.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pd.concat()`

```
pd.concat([df]*5).sort_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us do

```
out = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(5)).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[834]: 
   X  Y
0  A  2
1  A  2
2  A  2
3  A  2
4  A  2
5  B  1
6  B  1
7  B  1
8  B  1
9  B  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

```
out = df.apply(lambda x: np.repeat(x,5)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

print(out):

```
   X  Y
0  A  2
1  A  2
2  A  2
3  A  2
4  A  2
5  B  1
6  B  1
7  B  1
8  B  1
9  B  1
```